# How to rewrite the magento core-cache-model (Mage_Core_Model_Cache)

Tags: class, caching, magento, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite the core cache model. And this doesn't work. My first attempt to solve the problem was to try the rewrite with another model...
In my config.xml I declared the following

```
<global>         
  <models>          
    <core>
      <rewrite>
        <**layout**>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Core_Cache</**layout**>
      </rewrite>
    </core>
  </models>
  ....
```

and in my class I died in the consturctor.

This works perfectly!
So my may in rewriting models is the right one.

But If I don't use the layout-node in the xml but using the cache-node instead this does not work.

So my attempt is the following and this is not working:

```
<global>         
  <models>          
    <core>
      <rewrite>
        <cache>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Core_Cache</cache>
      </rewrite>
    </core>
  </models>
  ....
```

My question now: is there a way to rewrite / overload the "cache-core-model"???

Comment: looks fine to me... may be a cache issue :) clear cache ?

Comment: yeah looks fine to me too... I cleaned the cache and deleted the folders var/cache & var/session and if I change the cache-node to layout-node it immediately works :( for the layout model)

Comment: any other ideas why this doesn't work ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also trying to do the same thing and i don't think it's possible. If you var_dump out $this->_xml->group->models in the method: getGroupedClassName (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php) you'll notice that your rewrite it's not yet available, hence why it's skipped.

If you try to overwrite translate or layout: your_class_model you'll notice that the $this->_xml... dumps the initial core classes (with no rewrite) and you'll see your rewrite down the line well past the core/cache. So, it's probably being overridden but the class is already instantiated, set up and used; so it's really not going to fire anything.

Hence i don't think it's possible to override the core/cache. You'll have to move it to the app/code/local. Pitty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Yes this is the "solution" i also made... But it is not a good way in my eyes to copy core files into local. But this is obviously the only way to do so. A real pitty.

Answer (score 4):

The cache will be initialized before module configurations (config.xml) are loaded. The cache-Model was instanciated with Mage::getModel, which caches the modelnames in the registry.
 So all later tries to get the custom cache-model will also fail.

Solution: put this rewrite statement in the etc/local.xml. This is a bit dirty because the local.xml should only hold module independent stuff. But this is better than copying core files to local.

Comment: You said, is bit dirty, so, do you have another solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, but my solution is a little bit different to yours ;-)

Magento will load the XML file from /app/etc/*.xml (this files will not be cached) before everything else in magento.
So i created my own file here "cache.xml" and the content is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>          
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <cache>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Core_Cache</cache>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

works perfect in 1.6,1.7 and 1.8

Comment: This gives me `Fatal error: Call to a member function processRequest() on a non-object in /var/www/magento-20161207-1/mage-webroot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 351` on 1.9.2.4.